# Integrating payments into chatbot

Tags: botframework, payment-gateway, chatbot

I wanted to know if it is possible to integrate payments into a chatbot built upon MS Bot Framework without using PayPal/Stripe APIs. I've got a traditional payment gateway that I wish to use for payments, is there any way to render a webpage within a bot window? Also, I'm not entirely sure whether such an approach is safe.
Any other suggestions in terms of approaching this problem are also welcome.

Comment: Did you checkout the payment bot sample? It uses Stripe account tho. https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/CSharp/sample-payments

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use depends on the language you're using the [CSharp Payment Bot Sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/CSharp/sample-payments) or [Node Payment Bot Sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/Node/sample-payments) that uses Stripe or if you want to use PayPal, you can just create a [Payment Button](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/create_payment_button/) where the user will have to click on, get redirected to a browser to finish the payment and create an endpoint for PayPal's [Instant Payment Notification](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/products/instant-payment-notification/) on your Bot so it can tell when the payment has been processed.